# Semantic UI - change component styles (override components css)

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I'm trying to change the style of some semantic ui components. I've created a css file and I've been changing the parameters there. Then I noticed that all component css files (in Semantic UI folder) have the following code at the end:

```
/*******************************
         Theme Overrides
*******************************/


/*******************************
         Site Overrides
*******************************/
```

I've copy pasted the code from my css file to the bottom of the component css file but the styles were not updated/overrided. I tried to use `!important` but it didn't worked either.

I've tried something like this:

```
/*******************************
         Theme Overrides
*******************************/

.ui.header {
  border: solid red; !important
  border-width: 2px; !important
}
```

I was expecting this element to get a red border around it

```
<div class="ui small header">This is a header</div>
```

Any idea why it didn't worked ?

Comment: Are you using the same selectors? You need to use equal (valid if your CSS is placed **after** the default) or stronger selectors to override the default style.

Comment: Yes, I'm using exactly the same selectors. I was looking and I've deleted some folders of the original Semantic UI zip because I felt they were going to be useless. I'm betting the problem is caused because of those missing folder (just guessing, need to try).

Comment: If you deleted something necessary, you could take a look at console logs in your browser, those may report a **404 Not found**, this way you can figure out which files you need.

Comment: Just in case I've tested the above example with a "clean" Semantic UI zip folder. It also didn't worked.

Comment: Ok, I've tried out to override default header style, it worked out for me (without **!important**), BUT is it possible that you included the **semantic.min.css** and all your edits are inside the **semantic.css** ?

Comment: I finally did it ! First, you were right, I was including **semantic.min.css** and making the changes in **semantic.css**. Second, I wasn't using `gulp watch` or `gulp build` to "save the changes". Thanks !

Comment: Hey, glad you made it. I'm sorry I didn't respond earlier, had only my smartphone with me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your overriding CSS styles in *src/site/elements/header.overrides file* and run **gulp build** command.

If "**gulp watch**" is already running, then it will automatically run build task on detecting changes in the aforementioned file.

The **src/site** folder is present to override any style introduced by the selected theme.

Comment: How does Gulp have to do with anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Try including '!important' within ';' in your code like this,

> .ui.header {
>
> border: solid red !important;
>
> border-width: 2px !important;
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be to nest all your application's less styling under a unique id, used at the root element of your app.[image]

for example in my own case:

```
    #__next {

       .is-pink {

          color: pink

       }

      .mb-70 {

        margin-bottom: 70px !important;

       }

    }
```